# 240vac to 12vdc power supply

Tags: voltage-regulator

Ok ive built a 240v ac to 24v dc power supply to run my zvs driven flyback transformer. The guts of this psu is still out of the box because I'd like to install a 12v pc cooling fan. My question is, and I'm still quite new to all this, can I run a 24 to 12v dc/dc 7812 circuit in parallel with the 24v zvs supply? Post rectification of course. It might sound a silly question but id rather not fry anything by just smashing things together and seeing what happens. Thanks in advance for your help guys

Comment: You couldn't find a transformer with a 12V tap?

Comment: Yes but the only ones within my price range were rated 1 amp. I fried one of those already due to overheating and insulation failure i assume.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how much current you want at 12v. As the 7812 will be dropping 12v across it, 12*I watts will be lost in it as heat. If the current is reasonably low, or you have an adequate heatsink, then this need not be a problem.

If you only want to drive a fan, then that qualifies in my book as a reasonably low current, I'm guessing 2 watts max? You will want some extra heatsinking on the 7812 to get rid of 2W safely, but just screwing it to any metal surface should be adequate at that power level, there's no need for multi-finned things.

If your PC fan fried a 1A power supply, then I'd review carefully what you are doing, because that should not happen.

Comment: Thanks Neil, yes its just a small fan i pulled from an old pc psu. I want it as part of my build mainly for aesthetics. And heatsinks.. I've got hundreds of those oxidizing away in forgotten drawers around the place from crt dismantles :) Thanks for your help I'll get soldering right now! At 40 years old a new world has opened up to me: electronics is fascinating

Comment: By the way Neil it was the 30kv flyback load that fried the transformer not the fan which wasn't in the circuit at the time. The fan draws .07 amps at 12 volts or .84 amps :) I'm learning as i go

Comment: .84 watts i mean oh jeebs

Comment: At 840mW, you should (may) get away with the 7812 just sticking up in fresh air, though an extra tab of metal won't hurt.  I have been known, in fan supplies just like this, to reason that it's only getting hot when the fan is running, so I mount it in airflow of the fan. With added breeze, 840mW will be fine in an unheatsinked 7812.

Comment: Over in the corner is a little "server" I built from an old laptop motherboard, for email and media storage etc. I needed a 12V supply for the hard drive and just shoved a 7812 in series with it off the 20V input rail and it works fine. I put it on a little heatsink I had salvaged from a PSU (since the case I built for it has no fans and is just sorta-convective cooled). The 78/79 series are inefficient, but they are highly dependable and simple to use.